# Selenium code for Date picker in jquery

Tags: java, jquery, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select 22nd June 2015. My Concept is first i will check for the Year and move to that year and check for month in that year and move to it and finally click the particular date. Below is my Following code. The date picker in jquery.com

```
package common;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class Date2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String Date = "22-June-2015";
        String Splitter[] = Date.split("-");
        String Day = Splitter[0];
        String Month = Splitter[1];
        String Year = Splitter[2];
        int Year1 = Integer.parseInt(Year);

        System.out.println(Day);
        System.out.println(Month);
        System.out.println(Year);
        System.out.println("Int : "+Year1);

        RemoteWebDriver driver;

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();


        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/iframe")));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='datepicker']")).click();

        String Month_Present = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/div/span[1]")).getText();
        String Year_Present = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/div/span[2]")).getText();
        System.out.println(Month_Present);
        System.out.println(Year_Present);

        int Year_Present1 = Integer.parseInt(Year_Present);

        WebElement MoveBack_Calender = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/a[1]/span"));
        WebElement MoveForward_Calender = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/a[2]/span"));

        if (Year_Present1>Year1) {
            do {
                MoveBack_Calender.click();
            } while (Year_Present1==Year1);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: so what do you want now are you facing any problem or something else ?

Comment: Yes i am not able to move back or forward. No error is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please find the working code

public class DataPicker {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "D:\\eclipseProject\\StackOverFlow\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");

        // up-to year present i have copy pasted everything form your question 

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/iframe")));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='datepicker']")).click();

        String Month_Present = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/div/span[1]")).getText();
        String Year_Present = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/div/span[2]")).getText();
        System.out.println(Month_Present);
        System.out.println(Year_Present);

        // now implementing code as per your question

        // SOLUTION FIRST 
        // first solution is that you can pass simply value in the
        // input date box as it is taking value simply just by typing 

        // driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='datepicker']")).sendKeys("06/22/2015");

        // SOLUTION SECOND
        // there is no need to take Month and year separately 
        // hence talking them inside a single string 
        String Year_Month = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='ui-datepicker-title']")).getText();
        System.out.println(Year_Month);

        // click the previous year button only if current 
        // year and month  displayed is not May 2015

        for(int i =0;i<12;i++){
            // checking if year is 2015 or not
            Year_Month = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='ui-datepicker-title']")).getText();
            System.out.println(Year_Month);
            if(!Year_Month.equals("May 2015")){
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w']")).click(); 
            }
        }

        // now as we are inside the desired year month we can select date now
        List<WebElement> dataForMonth4 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@data-month='4']/a"));
        System.out.println("Total available dates to select in this month : " + dataForMonth4.size());

        for(int i=0;i<dataForMonth4.size();i++){
            System.out.println("Date is : " + dataForMonth4.get(i).getText());
            // now implement the logic of date selection
            if(dataForMonth4.get(i).getText().equals("22")){
                dataForMonth4.get(i).click();
            }
        }
}
```

}

Hope this helps you Thanks

Comment: Thanks Raj Its working for that month. But my intention is to move and click whatever the date i will give. Suppose if i give 3-Mar-2014. It should move back to that date and click that date. If i give 9-Jun-2016 it has to move forward and search for that month and click the date. for that only in my code i checked for the condition if the current year is greater than the desired date given then it should move back and if the current year is less than the date given it should move forward. This is what i required. If i am wrong please suggest me

Comment: i did above based on your question,yeah that can be done and i will update my answer when i will get some time Thanks for your feedback

Comment: thanks waiting for ur code. Meanwhile i will try in many ways